# How do I start an Errai / GWT application in Super Dev Mode with maven?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode, errai

I am unable to run an Errai/Gwt application in superDev Mode with the following command

```
mvn clean gwt:run
```

And I am receiving error. The errai framework uses the mojo gwt-maven and I can't make it work with the Tbroyer version. the error I am getting is "Module Load Failure" Could not shutdown JBoss As an instance... from the GWT Development Mode window. And If I look into the terminal the error I am getting is :

```
ERROR] Unable to start embedded HTTP server
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not deploy errai-tutorial.war:
[ERROR] Input:
[ERROR] {
[ERROR]     "operation" : "deploy",
[ERROR]     "address" : [{
[ERROR]         "deployment" : "errai-tutorial.war"
[ERROR]     }]
[ERROR] }
[ERROR] Output:
[ERROR] {
[ERROR]     "outcome" : "failed",
[ERROR]     "failure-description" : {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" : {"jboss.persistenceunit.webapp#forge-default" : "javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory cannot be created\n    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory cannot be created\n    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory cannot be created\n    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.stax.XMLEventFactoryImpl not found"}},
[ERROR]     "rolled-back" : true
[ERROR] }
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.as.JBossServletContainerAdaptor.attemptDeploymentRelatedOp(JBossServletContainerAdaptor.java:300)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.as.JBossServletContainerAdaptor.attemptDeploy(JBossServletContainerAdaptor.java:288)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.as.JBossServletContainerAdaptor.<init>(JBossServletContainerAdaptor.java:163)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.as.JBossServletContainerAdaptor.<init>(JBossServletContainerAdaptor.java:74)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher.start(EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher.java:111)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
```

Here is the default POM.Xml that the application comes with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.jboss.errai.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>errai-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>4.15.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Errai::Tutorial</name>

  <properties>
    <errai.version>${project.version}</errai.version>
    <gwt.version>2.8.2</gwt.version>
    <elemental.version>1.0.0-beta-1</elemental.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.5.11</slf4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <errai.dev.context>${project.artifactId}</errai.dev.context>
    <as.version>24</as.version>
    <!-- Add the absolute path for $JBOSS_HOME below to manage another instance -->
    <!-- <errai.jboss.home>${project.build.directory}/wildfly-${as.version}
    <errai.jboss.home>/opt/wildfly--${as.version}</errai.jboss.home>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repo</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-public</id>
      <name>Sonatype Public Snapshots Repo</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>errai-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${errai.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.elemental2</groupId>
       <artifactId>elemental2-dom</artifactId>
       <version>${elemental.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-javaee-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cordova</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
    <artifactId>errai-cdi-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.elemental2</groupId>
    <artifactId>elemental2-dom</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <skip />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>   
          <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
          <noServer>false</noServer>          
          <extraJvmArgs>-XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -Derrai.jboss.home=${errai.jboss.home} -Derrai.dev.context=${errai.dev.context}</extraJvmArgs>
          <server>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.EmbeddedWildFlyLauncher</server>
          <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
          <runTarget>${errai.dev.context}/</runTarget>
          <soycDetailed>false</soycDetailed>
          <hostedWebapp>src/main/webapp</hostedWebapp>
          <strict>true</strict>
          <compileReport>true</compileReport>
          <saveSource>true</saveSource>
          
        </configuration>
        
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${basedir}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>src/main/webapp/app/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deploy/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/</include>
                <include>.errai/</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>wildfly</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <packagingExcludes>**/javax/**/*.*,**/client/local/**/*.class</packagingExcludes>
              <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@-@{baseVersion}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
              <webResources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target/extra/app/src</directory>
                  <targetPath>src</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target/extra/app/symbolMaps</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>*.json</include>
                  </includes>
                  <targetPath>src</targetPath>
                </resource>
              </webResources>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
            <extensions>false</extensions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
          <artifactId>errai-jboss-as-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency><groupId>com.google.guava</groupId><artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.dom4j</groupId><artifactId>dom4j</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId><artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>        
        <dependency><groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId><artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>javax.inject</groupId><artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId><scope>provided</scope><version>1</version></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>javax.validation</groupId><artifactId>validation-api</artifactId><classifier>sources</classifier><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>javax.validation</groupId><artifactId>validation-api</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>junit</groupId><artifactId>junit</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId><classifier>sources</classifier><scope>provided</scope></dependency>        
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-codegen-gwt</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-data-binding</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-javax-enterprise</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-jaxrs-client</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-jpa-client</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-navigation</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-tools</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-ui</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId><artifactId>errai-html5</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId><artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId><artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId><scope>provided</scope><version>2.0.0.Final</version></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId><artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId><scope>provided</scope><version>2.0.0.CR1</version></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>xml-apis</groupId><artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>io.netty</groupId><artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId><scope>provided</scope></dependency>    
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I can't point out what I am missing. However I deploy the application. It builds fine and I can access it through the bed. But I want to be able to test without recompiling it all the time.

thanks for your assistance.

[image]